# Time locked wallet contract withdraw revert

Tags: web3js, truffle-contract, smart-contract-wallets, timelock

I have a time locked wallet code which withdraws the fund after some period:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';

contract TimeLockedWallet {

    address public creator;
    address public owner;
    uint256 public unlockDate;
    uint256 public createdAt;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    event Received(address from, uint256 amount);
    event Withdrew(address to, uint256 amount);
    event WithdrewTokens(address tokenContract, address to, uint256 amount);
    
    constructor(
        address _creator,
        address _owner,
        uint256 _unlockDate
    ) public {
        creator = _creator;
        owner = _owner;
        unlockDate = _unlockDate;
        createdAt = block.timestamp;
    }

    // keep all the ether sent to this address
    receive() external payable {
        Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    // callable by owner only, after specified time
    function withdraw() onlyOwner public {
       require(block.timestamp >= unlockDate, "reverted here");
       //now send all the balance
       payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
       emit Withdrew(msg.sender, address(this).balance);
    }

    // callable by owner only, after specified time, only for Tokens implementing ERC20
    function withdrawTokens(address _tokenContract) onlyOwner public {
       require(block.timestamp >= unlockDate);
       ERC20 token = ERC20(_tokenContract);
       //now send all the token balance
       uint256 tokenBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
       token.transfer(owner, tokenBalance);
       emit WithdrewTokens(_tokenContract, msg.sender, tokenBalance);
    }

    function info() public view returns(address, address, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        return (creator, owner, unlockDate, createdAt, address(this).balance);
    }

}
```

When I try to test the code above in JavaScript, it reverts:

```
let timelockWallet = new TimeLockedWallet(ownerWallet[0]);
await timelockWallet.send(ethToSend, {from: owner});
await timelockWallet.withdraw();
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: What version of Solidity are you using?

Comment: Hi Paul, it's 0.8.0

Answer (score 1):

Not definitively, but `onlyOwner` and `require` are the usual suspects. You should add reasons to `require(expression, "this is why it reverted");` statements to help with debugging.

I can't quite make out what Solidity version that is or what `Withdrew` is. It *looks like* an event emitter without `emit`. If it compiles, that sort of dates the compiler. It might be necessary to add a `fallback` or a `receive` function for the `send()` stage to work.

You should consider posting a complete example so people can replicate the error.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your suggestion. I have edited my post with full script. it's 0.8.0 version and I tested witout onlyOwner and add the comment. It's still reverted.